# __cdecl and __declspec calling conventions confusion

Tags: c++, c, dllimport, calling-convention

I am writing a DLL for a third party application. The main software engineer mentions that the application uses the __cdecl (/Gd) calling convention. That I need to make sure that I use that.

Additionally, the third party has provided to me a C++ DLL skeleton which exports the functions as follows:

```
#ifdef _EXPORTING
  #define DECLSPEC    __declspec(dllexport)
#else
   #define DECLSPEC    __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

#ifdef __cplusplus
   extern "C" {  
#endif

DECLSPEC int ICD_Create(char* id);
....
....
```

I am kind of confused. Why the functions are being exported using __declspec convention instead of __cdedl?? does __declspec support _cdecl?

Thanks.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`__declspec()` and `__cdecl` are addressing two different aspects of calling the function, and you can (and in this case by the sounds of it you should) use both.

`__cdecl` specifies the calling convention, which specifies how parameters are passed to the function via the stack, and, very importantly, who cleans up the stack afterwards (in the case of `__cdecl` it is the caller who tidies up).

`__declspec(dllimport/dllexport)` is used to simplify exporting function definitions from a DLL: you don't need to use them, but the other ways of exporting functions are quite klunky.

It is probably a good idea to explicitly use `__cdecl` rather than doing what the code snippet you have has done, which is rely on the compiler to choose the calling convention. You can override this with command-line switches I think, and I believe the default is different depending on whether you are compiling C or C++ code, so more explicit is (as usual) better.

Comment: So, where do I specify the calling convention. My impression is that it is specified as int __cdecl VB_Create(char *). Is this right?

Comment: Great, is the assignation of the calling convention something in the compiler or in the linker? Sounds to me that both are involved. is this right?

Comment: @Peretz, in your case you'll end up with something like `int DECLSPEC __cdecl VB_Create(char*)`.

Comment: @Peretz - re your 2nd question, I think in fact only the compiler needs to worry about the calling convention, because it generates code which will load parameters onto the stack, invoke the function, retrieve the return value, and tidy up the stack: the calling convention controls where that code is and what order things are put in. All the linker has to worry about is what the function address is & get that right.

Comment: Doesn't the `extern "C"` bit imply `__cdecl`?

Comment: @Dennis -- I don't have access to the C++ standard but I don't think that `extern "C"` does, or should, imply `__cdecl`. You can after all have `extern "C" __stdcall` for example. (And "imply" is too close to "assume", and you know where that ends up...!)

Answer (score 9):

These are orthogonal concepts.  `__declspec` just indicates the "storage class" of the entity in question.  In the context you're looking it, it's telling you whether you are specifying functions for import or export (this is usually an issue when working with code that could either be built as part of a DLL or directly included in an executable, depending on context).

More information on `__declspec` is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dabb5z75%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

the `__cdecl` calling convention indicates that the function uses the traditional "C" language convention for passing parameters.  There are other styles, notably `__stdcall`.

More details on `__cdecl` vs `__stdcall` (and others) are [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/01/08/48616.aspx).