# Acess Violation Protected Memory when editing a passed IntPtr from C# to native unmanaged C++ dll on net framework 4.5 and later

Tags: c#, c++, dllimport

I am using an C++ DLL functions by calling `DLLImport` in C#, the C# code manages the memory, while using .Net Framework 4, all was working fine, but when trying to upgrade to newest versions or even switching to net core, when i call functions on the C++ DLL that uses a `IntPtr` given from the C# code and then edit the data on this memory region, i get access violation read/write on protected memory, what was not happening on the net framework 4.

Tried searching for similar problems but could not identify people whose had an problem like this, cause the code did not change, only the net framework, and also did not found where it changed that make that do not works anymore.

This is one call that gives me access violation

```cs
[DllImport("ocgcore", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern void set_player_info(IntPtr pduel, Int32 playerid, Int32 lp, Int32 startcount, Int32 drawcount);
```

This is the C++ code in the DLL that receives the C# call

```cpp
extern "C" DECL_DLLEXPORT void set_player_info(ptr pduel, int32 playerid, int32 lp, int32 startcount, int32 drawcount) {
    duel* pd = (duel*)pduel;
    if(lp > 0)
        pd->game_field->player[playerid].lp = lp;
    if(startcount >= 0)
        pd->game_field->player[playerid].start_count = startcount;
    if(drawcount >= 0)
        pd->game_field->player[playerid].draw_count = drawcount;
}
```

This other code, does not gives me any problems, even using newest net core.
C# call

```cs
public static extern IntPtr create_duel(UInt32 seed);
[DllImport("ocgcore", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
```

C++ code that is called

```cpp
extern "C" DECL_DLLEXPORT ptr create_duel(uint32 seed) {
    duel* pduel = new duel();
    duel_set.insert(pduel);
    pduel->random.reset(seed);
    return (ptr)pduel;
}
```

I would expect it to work on the newest versions of .net and .net core, but for some reason, if I use anything newer than .Net Framework 4.0, it simply does not work, giving me this access violation on protected memory.

To briefly explain:

csproj with : `<TargetFramework>net40</TargetFramework>` Works perfectly.

csproj with : `<TargetFramework>net45</TargetFramework>` or any other version above 4.0 does not work, giving the same problem at the same place (not at compile, but at runtime), including net core.

Comment: And what do you pass for `pduel` when calling `set_player_info`?

Comment: The ```pduel``` is an ```IntPtr```, and its value is assigned by calling the ```create_duel```, and then passed to the ```set_player_info```

Comment: What is your actual [resulting calling convention](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6915132/11683) for the functions? Does your `DECL_DLLEXPORT` explicitly include `__cdecl`, and if it does not, can you add it?

Comment: I used the cdecl to call it from C# while on .Net Framework 4.0, and worked fine, but now on newer versions, it gives me the access violation problem. The define in  the C++ header is the following ```#define DECL_DLLEXPORT __declspec(dllexport)```

Comment: @GSerg I tried to explicitly include ```__cdecl``` on the C++ function, but stills does not work at all, gives me the same error as before.

Comment: Nothing obviously wrong here. If you build a simple example using just this code and a dummy library I expect it will work. Try that next.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan That is exactly my problem, the code works perfectly when targeting up to .Net Framework 4.0, but if the target is anything newer than that, it gives me this problem whenever i get to the point an pointer is passed to the unmanaged code and the memory is edited there.

Comment: Did you make the dummy dll that I suggested

Comment: Get the same problem ```Exception thrown at 0x00007FFAC9DDD3AE (ocgcore.dll) in Server.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0000000052437C18. occurred```, but works fine at .Net 4.0 though, im trying at net core 3.0 by the way, but even using net core 2, or anything from net framework 4.5 to 4.8, gives same results.

Comment: Please show the code for the dummy dll and the .NET code that calls it.

Comment: I only picked up the parts of the C++ and the .NET i showed and compiled, ignoring all the rest, and called it alone, getting same problem, its OpenSource, you can check in here: ```https://github.com/Fluorohydride/ygopro-core/blob/master/ocgapi.cpp```
```https://github.com/IceYGO/ygosharp/blob/master/YGOSharp.OCGWrapper/Api.cs```

Comment: I'm sorry, but we need questions to be self contained.